# How to integrate google map in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, dictionary

I have integrated **google map API** in my android app.
now i am programming same in ios. I am not understanding how to integrate **google map API in to my ios** app.
Or is it possible to integrate google map API in to ios app??
Please help me. If u have any tutorial it would be most appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MKMapView for that. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/21/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0/

Comment: Beware that with iOS 6 the MapKit does not work with Google maps (it do not use google api, neither google tiles).

Comment: hey when i am running mapkit tutorial it gives following error : Terminating since there is no system event server.
(Run the EventPump or pass the argument "-RegisterForSystemEvents" if you want to run without SpringBoard.

Comment: hey i solved that problem.Thanks Evol for such a great tutorial.